# Canon EDSDK - Audio levels

Tags: edsdk, canon-sdk

Is there any way to retrieve the real-time audio levels through the Canon EDSDK?

I know with the Nikon SDK it is sent as part of each Live View frame, but couldn't find any references for Canon.

Looking to use this with an EOS 750D.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't, no. Filming in general has quite poor support, you can basically only start and stop.

The live view frame metadata only contains info about the focus rectangle (position, size), zoom (level, position) and histogram (brightness and RGB).